# MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Out of range value for column 'agentID' at row 4

Tags: mysql, database, stored-procedures

In store procedure, I am using temporary table, agentID int(11) and inserting this value in agentID field 9999999999, is working with Server version: 5.5.29 MySQL Community Server (GPL). Now I am migrated on MySQL 5.6, this not working it shows the problem here (Data truncation: Out of range value for column 'agentID' at row 4). Please anyone explain me the reason why MySQL server behave different, it should the important.

Comment: Are you sure in 5.5 work?. In my tests both [MySQL 5.5](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5a88b/1) and [MySQL 5.6](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5a88b/1) the error occurs. Check: [MySQL 5.5 :: 11.2.1 Integer Types (Exact Value) - INTEGER, INT, SMALLINT, TINYINT, MEDIUMINT, BIGINT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/integer-types.html) and [MySQL 5.6 :: 11.2.1 Integer Types (Exact Value) - INTEGER, INT, SMALLINT, TINYINT, MEDIUMINT, BIGINT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/integer-types.html).

Comment: @wchiquito yes I wrote stored procedure before 2 years ago, its working fine. But Now i migrated latest version, then faced the problem.

Comment: Please, check [5.1.7 Server SQL Modes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/sql-mode.html) ([sql_mode](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_sql-mode)) on both servers (5.5 and 5.6). [11.2.6 Out-of-Range and Overflow Handling‌​](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/out-of-range-and-overflow.html). [SQL Fiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c4de6/1).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySql 5.6 support Integer upto: 2147483647

[image]

Comment: nwzhaider please the add link of above source also.